# Show Date/time in x axis using react d3

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, react-d3

I am very new in to react js. I want to show the date/time in the x axis of my graph. I have follow all the steps from

https://github.com/react-d3/react-d3-tooltip

I got the below error:

```
DOMPropertyOperations.js?930e:147 Error: <path> attribute d: Expected number, "MNaN,31.627906976…".
```

Here is my code:

```
render() {

    var generalChartData = require('./user.js');
    var dateFormatter = d3.time.format("%m-%Y");
  var chartSeries = [
      {
        field: 'age',
        name: 'Age',
        color: '#ff7f0e',

      },{
        field: 'index',
        name: 'index',
        color: '#A46CAD',

      }
    ],
    x = function(d) {
      return d.birthday;
    }
   return (

      <div className="wrapper">
        <LineTooltip
      width= {900}
      height= {500}
      data= {generalChartData}
      chartSeries= {chartSeries}
      x= {x}

    />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

date coming as: "birthday": "2011-01-17T00:00:00.000Z",

Answer (score 0):

You should rewrite your `x` function this way:

```
x = function(d) {
  return new Date(d.birthday);
}
```

Because of you have a date on x axis.

You also have to define `xScale="time"`, `xTicks` and `xTickFormat` props for correct ticks displaying on x axis. Look at [this working example](https://plnkr.co/edit/6f6mfjkftMKFzUEXsZDt?p=preview) for details.

```
<LineTooltip
  width={600}
  height={500}
  data={data}
  chartSeries={chartSeries}
  x={x}
  xScale="time"
  xTicks={[data.length, '']}
  xTickFormat={function(d) { return dateFormatter(new Date(d)) }}
/>
```